# dotnet restore fails when using nuget proxy on nexus

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nexus

I have a nuget proxy on Nexus (v 3.9.0-01) on an internal network. I haven't populated the local Nexus repo myself (and don't know how it was done or if any issues arose), however, I can upload new packages manually. The build takes place on Bamboo agent and cannot be connected to the public repository.

Because of the isolation, I have to run `dotnet build` / `dotnet publish` with `--no-restore` and restore the packages using `dotnet restore $projectPath --source $localNexus --runtime win-x64`

The packages are being restored just fine until `NuGet.Frameworks.4.7.0`. This package exists in 5 different versions ([as far as I can tell exact copy of the official nuget repo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Frameworks/)), just not plain 4.7.0 (which doesn't exist in the official repo either). Then, `dotnet restore` produces the following output:

```
build   20-Jun-2018 16:24:26    info :   GET https://nexus.***.***.***.au/repository/nuget.org-proxy/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common/2.8.0
build   20-Jun-2018 16:24:27    error: The feed 'https://nexus.***.***.***.au/repository/nuget.org-proxy/ [https://nexus.***.***.***.au/repository/nuget.org-proxy/]' lists package 'NuGet.Frameworks.4.7.0' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
build   20-Jun-2018 16:24:27    error:   Unable to find package 'NuGet.Frameworks.4.7.0'.
```

The restore operation fails even if I force the package using `dotnet add $projectPath` package --source $localNexus`before running`dotnet restore`.

*Note: this package is a dependency of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` in my project.*

Possibly related: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6159 (tagged with different Nexus version)

**Questions:**

- Why is the package restore failing (i.e. not pulling the most suitable 4.7.0-xxx)?
- Is it due to some Nexus quirks? Or corrupted package?
- Why does it not help to add the problematic package manually using `dotnet package add`?

Comment: A proxy repository is populated form the source repository as you request packages from it. You cannot simply upload new packages to a proxy repository - you need a hosted repository for that. My suspicion is that your nuget client is misconfigured. Can you show nuget repositories from your Nexus and your nuget  configuration?

Comment: any solution? same issue here

Comment: i am trying to configure my project to use a Nexus Repository already set up. Can you point me in the right direction so that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Having the exact same problem with Nexus 3.10, it appears this is resolved in 3.14 according to this Nexus issue; https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-17611